# Making sure no two random lines are the same.

Tags: java

The following code works great for picking random lines from a file. How do I make sure that no two lines occurs since random may repeat the same line again.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

String line = reader.readLine();
while( line != null ) {
    lines.add(line);
    line = reader.readLine();
}

Random r = new Random();
int i = 0;
while(i < 4){
    System.out.println(lines.get(r.nextInt(lines.size())));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Unless there is something special about your file, all you can do is to run through all lines you have and check every time before you add the new line. This process will get slower the more lines you get during the run.

Comment: Add the lines to a `Set`, if the line is already in the set `continue` before incrementing. Alternatively, read any four lines and then randomize them.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch CLEVER IDEA! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: Use a `Set` to keep track of which lines you've already used. Here, I added a check to make sure there is actually enough lines in the file to avoid an infinite loop.

```
// Number of lines to print
final int PRINT_COUNT = 4;

// Check to make sure there are actually 4 lines in the file
if(lines.size() < PRINT_COUNT)
    throw new IllegalStateException("Too few lines in file. Total lines="+lines.size());

// Declare a set to record which lines were selected
Set<Integer> chosen = new HashSet<>();

Random r = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < PRINT_COUNT;) {

    int nextInt = r.nextInt(lines.size());

    if(!chosen.contains(nextInt)){
        chosen.add(nextInt);
        System.out.println(lines.get(nextInt));
        i++; 
    }
}
```

*Note:* As a general rule, you want to reduce the scope of variables. For this reason, I converted your `while`-loop to a `for`-loop and only increment `i` when a unique line number is found.

Comment: Thank you so much ... Appreciate it